# Change background color of react-alert

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've successfully integrated react-alert into my dashboard but I want to change the alert's background color as it doesn't fit with the theme of my UI.

[Alert Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA7sV.png)

I've tried to change the background color from the template file which contains background color property but the change in it doesn't reflect.

Working codebox of react-alert:

https://codesandbox.io/s/l2mo430lzq

Do let me know if there is any solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own template and update the theme according to your need.

JS:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { positions, Provider } from "react-alert";
import Home from "./Home";
import "./style.css";

const options = {
  timeout: 500000,
  position: positions.BOTTOM_CENTER
};

const AlertTemplate = ({ message }) => (
  <div className="alert red-bg">{message}</div>
);

const App = () => (
  <Provider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>
    <Home />
  </Provider>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

CSS:

```
.red-bg {
  // Add extra styles which is matched with your theme
  background-color: red;
}
```